# Integral Inequality with Exponential

Tags: calculus

Prove that

$$ \int_{0}^{1} e^{x^2} dx <\frac{e+2}{3} $$

I know a solution (using power series) that gives an even lower bound, but I would really like to see what is the solution intended by the author. That 3 at the numerator suggest something with $\int_0^1 x^2dx$, so my only idea would be the inequality
$$\frac{e^{x}-e^{0}}{x}<e^x (Lagrange)$$ 
in which $x$ should be replaced by $x^2$, so
$$\frac{e^{x^2}-e^{0}}{x^2}<e^{x^2} $$

Comment: $\frac{e+2}{3} = \frac{1}{3}e^1 + \frac{2}{3}e^0$ and $e^{x^2}$ is convex over $[0,1]$, maybe this can help, I am not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the power series expansion for the exponential function, we have
$$\int_0^1e^{x^2}dx=\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n}}{n!}dx\\=\left[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}\right]_{x=0}^{x=1}\\<\left[x+\frac{1}{3}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{n!}\right)\right]_{x=0}^{x=1}\\=\left[x-\frac{x}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2n+1}}{n!}\right)\right]_{x=0}^{x=1}\\=\frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\right)\\=\frac{e+2}{3}$$

Comment: Thank you! I kept using only Lagrange-based inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

This follows directly from the estimate $e^x < 1+(e-1)x$ for all $x\in(0,1)$.

Comment: Inequality which can be derived from the expansion of the exponential. Thank you!